# Why TCS Mockvita platform shows error for this problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

Can Anyone help me with this.I'm getting runtime error for this in online editor as well as in uploading the file but works with correct output in VS Code.

**Problem Description**
Given two numbers n1 and n2

1. Find prime numbers between n1 and n2, then
2. Make all possible unique combinations of numbers from the prime numbers list you found in step 1.
3. From this new list, again find all prime numbers.
4. Find smallest (a) and largest (b) number from the 2nd generated list, also count of this list.
5. Consider smallest and largest number as the 1st and 2nd number to generate Fibonacci series respectively till the count (number of primes in the 2nd list).
6. Print the last number of a Fibonacci series as an output

**Constraints**
2 <= n1, n2 <= 100

n2 - n1 >= 35

**Input Format**
One line containing two space separated integers n1 and n2.

**Output**
Last number of a generated Fibonacci series.

**Timeout**
1

**Test Case**
*Example 1*

**Input**

2 40

**Output**

13158006689

**Explanation**

1st prime list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]

Combination of all the primes = [23, 25, 27, 211, 213, 217, 219, 223, 229, 231, 32, 35, 37, 311, 313, 319, 323, 329, 331, 337, 52, 53, 57, 511, 513, 517, 519, 523, 529, 531, 537, 72, 73, 75, 711, 713, 717, 719, 723, 729, 731, 737, 112, 113, 115, 117, 1113, 1117, 1119, 1123, 1129, 1131, 1137, 132, 133, 135, 137, 1311, 1317, 1319, 1323, 1329, 1331, 1337, 172, 173, 175, 177, 1711, 1713, 1719, 1723, 1729, 1731, 1737, 192, 193, 195, 197, 1911, 1913, 1917, 1923, 1929, 1931, 1937, 232, 233, 235, 237, 2311, 2313, 2317, 2319, 2329, 2331, 2337, 292, 293, 295, 297, 2911, 2913, 2917, 2919, 2923, 2931, 2937, 312, 315, 317, 3111, 3113, 3117, 3119, 3123, 3129, 3137, 372, 373, 375, 377, 3711, 3713, 3717, 3719, 3723, 3729, 3731]

2nd prime list=[193, 3137, 197, 2311, 3719, 73, 137, 331, 523, 1931, 719, 337, 211, 23, 1117, 223, 1123, 229, 37, 293, 2917, 1319, 1129, 233, 173, 3119, 113, 53, 373, 311, 313, 1913, 1723, 317]

smallest (a) = 23

largest (b) = 3719

Therefore, the last number of a Fibonacci series i.e. 34th Fibonacci number in the series that has 23 and 3719 as the first 2 numbers is 13158006689

**Example 2**

*Input*

30 70

**Output**

2027041

**Explanation**

1st prime list=[31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67]

2nd prime list generated form combination of 1st prime list = [3137, 5953, 5347, 6761, 3761, 4337, 6737, 6131, 3767, 4759, 4153, 3167, 4159, 6143]

smallest prime in 2nd list=3137
largest prime in 2nd list=6761

Therefore, the last number of a Fibonacci series i.e. 14th Fibonacci number in the series that has 3137 and 6761 as the first 2 numbers is 2027041

The code i did is:

```
def isPrime(num):  #function to check for prime Number
    if(num>1):
        flag=0
        for i in range(2,num):
            if(num%i==0):
                flag=1
                break
        if(flag==0):
            return True  #it  is a prime number
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False

n,m=map(int,input().split())
first=[int(x) for x in range(n,m) if (isPrime(x))] #first list that contains prime numbers between n and m
second=[]
for i in first:
    for j in first:
        if(i!=j):
            second.append(str(i)+str(j))
prime=list(set([int(x) for x in second if isPrime(int(x))]))
a=min(prime)
b=max(prime)
fib=[a,b]
for i in range(len(prime)-2):
    c=a+b
    a=b
    b=c
    fib.append(c)

print(int(fib[len(prime)-1]))
```

Comment: Post the whole error message, please.

Comment: it shows runtime error when online editor is used and shows wrong answer when file is uploaded.No other details @Thomas